# Why is the button click event fired despite it being disabled in Aurelia?

Tags: aurelia

I have the following `button` which I want to only be active (click enabled) when a given condition is met however despite *visually* disabling the `button` the `click` event is still fired when the user clicks.

```
<button class="btn btn-default" click.delegate="doSomething()" type="submit" disabled.bind="true"></button>
```

**[Update]**
Changed `false` to `true` I mistakenly inserted wrong flag when cleaning up the example to post here. The question is still valid.

Comment: How are you trying to visually disable the button?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Quick workaround is to use `click.trigger` instead of `click.delegate` in this case. https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues/163

Comment: @BuildingJarl I have not yet found a proper solution but thanks for the workaround.

Comment: @MaYaN, please review the answers again after updates.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You're binding the `disabled` property to the value false, which means that the attribute `disabled` will not be added to the button. If you want the button to be disabled, do this:</s>

`<button class="btn btn-default" click.delegate="doSomething()" type="submit" disabled.bind="true"></button>`

**Edit: Based off question change**
*Your code works*. When you have the disabled attribute on the element, then this button is disabled, meaning that a click event can't fire, and if the click event can't fire, then you're not going to hit that `doSomething` function.
Reasons your function might still fire are probably based elsewhere in your code. With event bubbling, it's quite possible that another event fired, and bubbled up to the point of firing `doSomething`, but honestly, without enough context of the code, the specific reason your function is still being called cannot be determined.

**TL;DR**
Your code works in a clean environment, if it's still failing for you, then there's something else in your code base causing this.

Comment: @MaYaN, If you're asking how to disable a button, then what I provided (and what you updated to) *works*. If what you have is still calling the `doSomething()` function, then you have other code that is causing your issue. The `disabled` attribute on a button does not just _visually_ disable it, it disables the actual click function

Comment: Well that is what I expected as well but it is not :-) I see if I can put together a jsFiddle

Comment: I just tested that with the skeleton project and it does behave as expected. If you can create a fiddle, or a gist, that would be great.

Comment: @MaYaN, have you gotten a fiddle to test this out yet? This solution is still valid, behaves as expected, and can be reproduced. Your question changed to use the same code, and I'm telling you, it works. Therefore if it doesn't work, you have code elsewhere that is causing this issue. I'll update this answer to represent this.

Answer (score -1):

`disabled.bind` needs to be set to true to prevent the `click.delegate="doSomething()"` from being fired. Trying exposing a Boolean variable in the view-model and changing `disabled.bind="false"` to `disabled.bind="someBoolVar"`. When a certain condition is met, set someBoolVar to true or false in the view-model; that will determine if the event associated with the button is triggered.